# Spans add up to 12 but won't fit in row bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am really struggling with twitter bootstrap. I have the following spans, which add up to 12, yet the thrid item appears on a separate line.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

        <div class="span6 offset6">

                <div class="span2">Contact</div>
                <div class="span2">About Us</div>
                <div class="span2">Blog</div>



</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is what I get...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typo is `span 6`, it should be `span6`

```
<div class="span 6 offset6">
```

Should be:

```
<div class="span6 offset6">
```

Not doing so will place a small div to the left of your three span3's, thus moving them a bit sideways.

Updated: You will need to place the div's in their seperate `row` or `row-fluid` div's to align them properly.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that was when I cut and paste, have adjusted now, same result though